# python: convert base64 encoded png image to jpg

Tags: python, image, png, jpeg

I want to convert some base64 encoded png images to jpg using python. I know how to decode from base64 back to raw:

```
import base64 
pngraw = base64.decodestring(png_b64text)
```

but how can I convert this now to jpg? Just writing pngraw to a file obviously only gives me a png file. **I know I can use PIL, but HOW exactly would I do it?** Thanks!

Comment: Please remember to accept answers to your questions. You've only done that for one of your last ten questions.

Comment: @memyself Added a code example for PIL to my answer.

Comment: You know the process you applied to figure out how to use the `base64` module? Why not apply it to `PIL` as well?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/):

```
data = b'''iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAIBJRE
          FUOMvN08ENgCAMheG/TGniEo7iEiZuqTeiUkoLHORK++Ul8ODPZ92XS2ZiADITmwI+sWHwi
          w2BGtYN1jCAZF1GMYDkGfJix3ZK8g57sJywteTFClBbjmAq+ESiGIBEX9nCqgl7sfyxIykt
          7NUUD9rCiupZqAdTu6yhXgzgBtNFSXQ1+FPTAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'''

import base64
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
im.save('accept.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

In very old Python versions (2.5 and older), replace `b'''` with `'''` and `from io import BytesIO` with `from StringIO import StringIO`.

Comment: I had to `pip install Pillow` in order to `import PIL` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/installing-pil-with-pip

Answer (score 4):

Right from the PIL tutorial:

> To save a file, use the save method of the Image class. When saving files, the name becomes important. Unless you specify the format, the library uses the filename extension to discover which file storage format to use.

### Convert files to JPEG

```
import os, sys
import Image

for infile in sys.argv[1:]:
    f, e = os.path.splitext(infile)
    outfile = f + ".jpg"
    if infile != outfile:
        try:
            Image.open(infile).save(outfile)
        except IOError:
            print "cannot convert", infile
```

So all you have to do is set the file extension to `.jpeg` or `.jpg` and it will convert the image automatically.