# How to install PIL with pip on Mac OS?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, installation, python-imaging-library

I am trying to install PIL (the Python Imaging Library) using the command:

```
sudo pip install pil
```

but I get the following message:

```
Downloading/unpacking PIL
  You are installing a potentially insecure and unverifiable file. Future versions of pip will default to disallowing insecure files.
  Downloading PIL-1.1.7.tar.gz (506kB): 506kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package PIL
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
    
Installing collected packages: PIL
  Running setup.py install for PIL
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
    --- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks
    building '_imaging' extension
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -IlibImaging -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/_imaging.o
    unable to execute clang: No such file or directory
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/PIL/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-AYrxVD-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py

running install

running build

.
.
.
.

copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7

running build_ext

--- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks

building '_imaging' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/libImaging

clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -IlibImaging -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/_imaging.o

unable to execute clang: No such file or directory

error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up…
```

Could you please help me to install `PIL`?

Comment: Have you installed Xcode and then installed Xcode's command line tools? It looks like you don't have the clang compiler.

Comment: The PIL repository is not on pip

Answer (score 672):

1. Install Xcode and Xcode Command Line Tools as mentioned.
2. Use Pillow instead, as PIL is basically dead. Pillow is a maintained fork of PIL.

https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/

```
pip install Pillow
```

If you have both Pythons installed and want to install this for Python3:

```
python3 -m pip install Pillow
```

Comment: I got a `clang` error on OSX Mavericks when I tried this, but I found that this answer helped with that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22322645/16959

Comment: While this is a valid and useful answer, it really doesn't answer the question.  For those of us in the process of rehabbing old projects which may require filling a PIL dependency just so we can find the next thing that will break, we actually kind of need to get the actual dependency (and sometimes even need to get a specific version that someone built a hack on).

Comment: @Namey  Porting existing PIL code to Pillow can be done **easily**. [Port PIL to Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/porting-pil-to-pillow.html) .     Pillow is based on the PIL code, and has evolved into a better, modern and more friendly version of PIL.

Comment: @GiriB Thanks for the update.  My main point was that there are often cases where you are starting up work on some legacy production code where there are 20 ancient dependencies, of which PIL might be one, and you need to debug something to make a fix in the production code.  In that case, you most assuredly *do not* want to have to write ports for code connected to ~10 different libraries on your dev build just to start debugging the one-line error that is occurring in the production environment.  Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I'm trying to use a library which uses `import Image`. Is there a way to get Pillow to provide Image?

Answer (score 63):

This works for me:

```
apt-get install python-dev
apt-get install libjpeg-dev
apt-get install libjpeg8-dev
apt-get install libpng3
apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib

pip install PIL  --allow-unverified PIL --allow-all-external
```

Comment: On 64 bit platforms, the linked path needs to be different -- e.g. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so .  For a more architecture independent solution, create the links like `# ln -s /usr/lib/\`uname -i\`-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/`

Comment: Always the same problem for headers of imaging: _imagingft.c:73:31: fatal error: freetype/fterrors.h: No such file or directory

 #include <freetype/fterrors.h> So you have to install python-imaging throught pip

Comment: Always a problem in freetype headers like mentionned here [http://askubuntu.com/questions/507459/pil-install-in-ubuntu-14-04-1-lts]? SOlution : cd /usr/include
ln -s freetype2 freetype

Comment: under ubuntu 14.04 1 more symlink is necessary

`sudo ln -s /usr/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/freetype`

Comment: worked well for me the secret was the --allow-unverified PIL --allow-all-external

Answer (score 57):

It is very simple using apt install use this command to get it done

```
sudo apt-get install python-PIL
```

or

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

or

```
sudo easy_install pillow
```

Comment: don't forget to restart your ipython notebook server if you're running one.

Comment: sudo pip install pillow worked for me. sudo apt-get install python-PIL
 didn't.

Comment: I found it to be case sensitive so:
sudo apt-get install python-PIL => Failed (no package found)
sudo apt-get install python-pil => Worked

Answer (score 36):

Install

```
pip install Pillow
```

Then, Just import in your file like,

```
from PIL import Image
```

I am using windows. It is working for me.

> **NOTE**:
>
> Pillow is a functional drop-in replacement for the Python Imaging
>   Library. To run your existing PIL-compatible code with Pillow, it
>   needs to be modified to import the Imaging module from the PIL
>   namespace instead of the global namespace.

i.e. change:

`import Image`

to:

`from PIL import Image`

https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/2.2.1/

Comment: Thanks! When reading the name 'PIL' in `from PIL import Image` I could never guess the name of this library was 'Pillow'. I am also on Windows and your solution worked for me.

Comment: Pillow is a functional drop-in replacement for the Python Imaging Library. To run your existing PIL-compatible code with Pillow, it needs to be modified to import the Imaging module from the PIL namespace instead of the global namespace. I.e. change: ```import Image``` to ```from PIL import Image```

https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/2.2.1/

Comment: Thank you for the additional bckground information!

Answer (score 35):

On Mac OS X, use this command:

```
sudo pip install https://effbot.org/media/downloads/Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz
```

Comment: worked on debian jessy as well!, just needed to install python-dev beforehand :)

Comment: I had to install libjpeg first: 

````brew install libjpeg````

Comment: Finally an actual solution. My Mac doesn't have apt-get :p, and I want to install in a virtualenv anyway.

Comment: use sudo pip install Pillow - as below.

Answer (score 35):

You should install as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil):

```
pip install image
```

Answer (score 26):

I got the answer from a discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/opentreemap-user/3eGxGUgzA4Q/JwTrpXXGUSQJ):

I tried

```
pip install --no-index -f http://dist.plone.org/thirdparty/ -U PIL
```

and it worked.

Comment: Consider using this: `pip install --no-index -f http://effbot.org/downloads/ -U PIL --trusted-host effbot.org` The reason I used this one is because it is the URL listed by the package and on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL

Comment: I got a warning to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. After changing the URL it worked great.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn That almost worked except I got a compiler error where it can't find X11/Xlib.h

Comment: @Uncommon I'm not sure what the issue is there, sorry.

Answer (score 12):

I take it you're on Mac. See [How can I install PIL on mac os x 10.7.2 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070074/how-to-install-pil-on-mac-os-x-10-7-2-lion)

> If you use [homebrew](https://brew.sh), you can install the PIL with just `brew install pil`.  You may then need to add the install directory (`$(brew --prefix)/lib/python2.7/site-packages`) to your PYTHONPATH, or add the location of PIL directory itself in a file called `PIL.pth` file in
> any of your site-packages directories, with the contents:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
> ```
>
> (assuming `brew --prefix` is `/usr/local`).
>
> Alternatively, you can just download/build/install it from source:
>
> ```
> # download
> curl -O -L http://effbot.org/media/downloads/Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz
> # extract
> tar -xzf Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz
> cd Imaging-1.1.7
> # build and install
> python setup.py build
> sudo python setup.py install
> # or install it for just you without requiring admin permissions:
> # python setup.py install --user
> ```
>
> I ran the above just now (on OSX 10.7.2, with XCode 4.2.1 and System
> Python 2.7.1) and it built just fine, though there is a possibility
> that something in my environment is non-default.

Comment: While this explains how to install `pil`, it doesn't do it via `pip` as OP tried initially. I find the abundant use of `brew` around the web these days suboptimal. `brew` will install quite a bit of overhead depending on what you want it to do. so `pip` would probably still be the best choice for python modules.

Answer (score 11):

For Ubuntu, PIL is not working any more. I always get:

> No matching distribution found for PIL

So install python-imaging:

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging
```

Answer (score 11):

These days, everyone uses Pillow, a friendly PIL fork, over PIL.

Instead of: `sudo pip install pil`

Do: `sudo pip install pillow`

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-imaging
$ sudo -H pip install pillow
```

Comment: I would recommend against ever doing `sudo pip install ...`. That could end up breaking your system's installation of Python, which may affect applications of your system. Try using [Anaconda virtual environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-environments), [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or Docker.

Answer (score 6):

I'm having the same problem, but it gets solved with installation of `python-dev`.

Before installing PIL, run following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Then install PIL:

```
pip install PIL
```

Comment: This did not  work for me on Ubuntu 14. `pip install pil` results in `No distributions at all found for PIL`, whether I install python-dev first or not.

Answer (score 5):

For CentOS:

```
yum install python-imaging
```

Answer (score 5):

I had some errors during installation. Just in case somebody has this too. Despite that I already was sitting under admin user, but not root.

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL'

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/wzbozon/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Adding "sudo" solved the problem, with sudo it worked:

```
~/Documents/mv-server: $ sudo pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried all the answers, but failed.
Directly get the source from the official site and then build install success.

1. Go to the site http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/#pil117
2. Click "Python Imaging Library 1.1.7 Source Kit" to download the source
3. `tar xf Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz`
4. `cd Imaging-1.1.7`
5. `sudo python setup.py install`

Answer (score 3):

I nailed it by using `sudo port install py27-Pillow`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Comment: Note that this command timed out for me. Anyway, it will be deprecated in a few weeks. `sudo pip install --allow-external --allow-unverified PIL PIL` may also work for now.

Comment: `--allow-external` and `--allow-unverified` are both deprecated. `pip install pillow` is the correct answer.

Comment: The answer I posted was suggested to me by the stderr. So while my answer is now out of date, it wasn't at the time I wrote it. Also, I apologize for my message directed to JasonMc92 (which has since been removed). My tone was out of line, but my sentiment remains. There's something distasteful about trolling the front page and copy/pasting your note about "imparting underlying logic". Perhaps you're badge chasing, and I guess that's fine, but for the sake of consistency, please leave a comment on all the other similar answers to this question that fail to underly logic.

Answer (score 3):

(Window) If Pilow not work try download pil at  http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Answer (score 3):

- First you should run this `sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging` which will give you all the dependencies that you might need
- Then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade`
- Followed by `sudo apt-get install python-pip`
- And then finally install Pil `pip install pillow`

Answer (score 2):

Search on package manager before using `pip`. On Arch linux you can get PIL by `pacman -S python2-pillow`

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu, you can install PIL using `apt install`:

For Python 3 use:

```
sudo apt install python3-pil
```

For Python 2 use:

```
sudo apt install python-pil
```

Where `pil` should be lowercase as Clarkey252 points out

Comment: Does `apt` exist as package manager for macOS?

Comment: Sorry this is for ubuntu

Comment: The tag, the title and the example says "macos". Why are you posting answer about Ubuntu?

Comment: I understand your frustration and you are right, this question page is messed up. There are more “Ubuntu”, “Windows”, “Linux” answers than MacOs on this question. “pillow” and even “image”  are answered more often than PIL. NO solution actually does answer this question! However all solutions are based on bash and are often transferrable. The PIL repository is not on pip anyway so the only true answer is “you can’t”

Comment: @Ricoter ok so, why don't you integrate this message into your aswer as a "you can't BUT on ubuntu you can do this ...., so on a macos environment you can translate it into this... ". It will be much more descriptive and comprehensive as answer the I, as a _guy that's searching for the right answer_, will have achieved my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There's another Python package tool called [`conda`](http://continuum.io/downloads). Conda is preferred (I believe) over pip when there are libraries that need to install C++ and other bindings that aren't pure Python. Conda includes pip in its installation as well so you can still use pip, but you also get the benefits of conda.

Conda also installs [IPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython), pil, and many other libraries by default. I think you'll like it.