# Cannot Install Pip with version 1.5

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, pip

Cannot install pil

tried using

```
$ sudo pip install pil

Downloading/unpacking pil
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pil
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external pil to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pil
```

Because of version 1.5, and increased security, I tired:

```
sudo pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

And I get this message afterwards, I have command line tools installed for Xcode, however, I had to install it directly from the terminal to do so. In any case I'm not quite sure what is going on.

```
$sudo pip install pil --allow-external pil --allow-unverified pil
Downloading/unpacking pil
  pil is potentially insecure and unverifiable.
  Downloading PIL-1.1.7.tar.gz (506kB): 506kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pil/setup.py) egg_info for package pil
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py

Installing collected packages: pil
  Running setup.py install for pil
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
    --- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks
    building '_imaging' extension
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Headers -IlibImaging -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include -I/usr/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_imaging.o
    clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
    clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pil/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-O3PLEG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ArgImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageFileIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageGL.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

running build_ext

--- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks

building '_imaging' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/libImaging

cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Headers -IlibImaging -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include -I/usr/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_imaging.o

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pil/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-O3PLEG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/pil
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/sethmcfall/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/installing-pil-with-pip) for similar issues and ways to resolve.

Comment: Did you try the second command with `sudo`?

Comment: Yes i did, it still didn't work.