# Can't install Django Pillow: clang: error: no such file or directory

Tags: python, django, installation, python-imaging-library

I tried running `sudo ARCHFLAG=-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install Pillow`, but it fails with the following output:

```
cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_imaging.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/decode.o ... continued ...

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_imaging.o'

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/decode.o'

...etc...

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
```

What's the proper way of getting these files?

Comment: What happens if you do a simple `pip install Pillow`?

Comment: @rnevius The same error occurs. I set the `ARCHFLAG` so that it won't raise an error for invalid compiler flags.

Comment: maybe answers from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/installing-pil-with-pip can help you

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't seem to be a related issue, unfortunately.