# How to get LBForum (0.9.22) to run

Tags: python, django

I've installed and configured the Django app LBForum on Windows 8.1 and cannot get it to run.  My ultimate goal is to get it to run alongside Mezzanine, but I can't even get it to run on its own.

Here's what I've done:

(As a precondition to the following steps, I have the following C/C++ compiler installed to support pip.   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266. The batch file `vcvarsall.bat` is on the path environment variable.)

1. Perform a fresh install of python 2.78.  I used the ActiveState distribution 64 bit.
2. I then uninstall and reinstall virtualenv because of a bug as per these instructions (https://askubuntu.com/questions/400343/trying-to-create-a-python-virtual-environment-but-getting-oserror)
3. Next I activate the new environment `env\Scripts\activate.bat`
4. Next install lbform with `pip install lbforum` which fails because of "PIL" so I install that by itself.  `pip install PIL  --allow-unverified PIL --allow-all-external` per [Installing PIL with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/installing-pil-with-pip).
5. Then install lbform with `pip install lbforum` which seems to work fine as it reports success
6. Next I use the standard django commands for creating a site and adding a project.
7. I update the `urls.py` and the settings file for the site per the instructions found here: https://github.com/vicalloy/LBForum. Leaving off step 7.

When I run the app I see the following errors:

```
RuntimeError: South does not support Django 1.7 or higher. Please use native Django migrations.
```

I get different errors when running along Mezzanine but I'll create a different question for that once I know how to get this to run stand along in its own virtualenv.

**Update:** I've made some progress on this by removing south from INSTALLED_APPS. After doing so I was able to run .\manage.py migrate successfully. However I know see other errors:

```
File "c:\Users\cmedcoff\envlbf\lib\site-packages\attachments\urls.py" in <module>
    1. from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

    Exception Type: ImportError at /
    Exception Value: No module named defaults
```

Apparently the package django-lb-attachments (0.8.3) is looking for the package/module "django.conf.urls.defaults" which does not exists in version Django (1.7.7)? So I guess lbforum docs suggest that Django 1.3+ is supported but this is not the case for 1.7.7 without import edits?

Answer (score 1):

The problem when you install lbforum which in pypi [last update was on 2011](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/LBForum).
The project has set the Django dependency as **Django>=1.3, so it will install Django 1.7** :S.
Similar thing happends with PIL, you should install Pillow instead of PIL.

Also this project seems to be [incompatible with Django 1.5](https://github.com/vicalloy/LBForum/issues/15) and [has some out dated deps](https://github.com/vicalloy/LBForum/issues/19)
I think you need to follow this steps (I tried them on linux)

```
pip install Django==1.3
```

**However I will recommend to use the latest version of Django.**

you can try to install dev version with this command (you will need git), but it seems to be not compatible with Django 1.5

```
pip install git+https://github.com/vicalloy/LBForum
```

Tehere is a **fork which it seems to be compatible with Django 1.5+**, but I didn't have time to check it.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/bjinwright/LBForum
```

[check it here](https://github.com/bjinwright/LBForum)

For installing Pillow instead of PIL

```
pip uninstall PIL
pip install Pillow
```