# What does this pip error means when installing a package?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

When I am trying to install a package,The package is getting downloaded and at the end -

sorry this is the full log. I couldn't format it correctly.

```
Downloading/unpacking pillow
```

Downloading Pillow-3.0.0.tar.gz (9.6MB): 9.6MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_vamsi/pillow/setup.py) egg_info for package pillow

Installing collected packages: pillow
  Running setup.py install for pillow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip_build_vamsi/pillow/setup.py", line 767, in <module>
    zip_safe=not debug_build(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 601, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 337, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/tmp/pip_build_vamsi/pillow/setup.py", line 515, in build_extensions
    % (f, f))
ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting.
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_vamsi/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-YF9qhC-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
```

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

running egg_info

writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

copying PIL/OleFileIO-README.md -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/PIL

running build_ext

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "/tmp/pip_build_vamsi/pillow/setup.py", line 767, in

```
zip_safe=not debug_build(),
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup

```
dist.run_commands()
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

```
self.run_command(cmd)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

```
cmd_obj.run()
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run

```
return orig.install.run(self)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 601, in run

```
self.run_command('build')
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

```
self.distribution.run_command(command)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

```
cmd_obj.run()
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run

```
self.run_command(cmd_name)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

```
self.distribution.run_command(command)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

```
cmd_obj.run()
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 337, in run

```
self.build_extensions()
```

File "/tmp/pip_build_vamsi/pillow/setup.py", line 515, in build_extensions

```
% (f, f))
```

ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting.

---

Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip_build_vamsi/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-YF9qhC-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_vamsi/pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /home/vamsi/.pip/pip.log

I got this error when running pip install pillow command in lubuntu. I am having python 2.7

I already tried this command pip install -U setuptools which was suggested in some other post, but to no effect.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PIL with pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/installing-pil-with-pip)

Comment: Please show the entire output. The line containing the error is somewhere above the output you posted.

Comment: It means exactly what it says: that `--single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1`. In other words, it mean the compile failed. Why the compile failed isn't possible to tell from the output you provided. Anyhow, the [installation guide](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/installation.html#linux-installation) suggests that you "consider using native operating system packages first to avoid installation problems." In the event that you can't or don't want to use the native package, did you ensure you have the per-requisities listed there?

Answer (score 0):

First off, running the commands as a user with root priviledges is not the same thing as using sudo pip install "whateveryouaretryingtoinstall", just making sure that is clear. As said earlier, it looks like some kind of compilation error, so try installing pip again and then run it. If that doesn't work try installing the package manually and if that doesn't work, than it must be a problem with the package.

Comment: How so? I have been doing sudo pip install for a long time.