# how to install modules correctly in Pycharm?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I want to install PIL in python, but it seems I can't install the module correctly, is there anything that can solve the problem?
(My python version is 2.7)

[image]

Comment: Update `pip` and consider using [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) instead of PIL.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/20061019/524743

Answer (score 2):

Try installing Pillow, I was facing the same problem and then I figured out that PIL can be installed using the following.

```
pip install Pillow
```

Comment: technically it's Pillow, not PIL.  Pillow forked from PIL, which is no longer being maintained, iirc.

Answer (score 1):

Find your Python path:

```
which python
/Users/gogasca/anaconda/bin/python
```

You can install it from IDE itself or Project Settings:

```
Settings | Project | Project Interpreter | Select the right path, Click + and add pil Library
```

You can install from there. For me 1.1.7 worked in Pycharm 5.0.4 in OSX Python 2.7.10. Other alternatives is via CLI or Pillow

[image]

or from within pycharm terminal "pip install pillow"

Answer (score 0):

if you get something like:

> **Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-owgbzt7s\Pil low\setup.**

or

> **Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-owgbzt7s\Pil low\setup.py", line 907, in 
>           raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
>       __main__.RequiredDependencyException:**

while installing Pillow , then there is some problem with your pip.
the version creating this issue are pip 19.xx.xx and Pillow 7.0.0

Solution(worked for me)

For PyCharm:

1. Go to settings > Project: (your project name) > Project Interpreter.
2. Double click on pip, check specify version which should be 20.0.2+ and click on "Install Package". This will reinstall pip for you.
3. Now either search for Pillow in same window and click on install or use `python -m pip install Pillow` in terminal of PyCharm.

For non PyCharm or Terminal Users:

1. uninstall pip `apt-get remove --purge python-pip`
2. install pip `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python`