# Python Firebase issue No module named firebase_admin

Tags: python, python-2.7, firebase, firebase-admin

I have deployed a python code in Google App Engine.In my code,tried to import firebase_admin,but it shows following error,

```
import firebase_admin
ImportError: No module named firebase_admin
```

**hello.py**

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
```

I tried simple python code using Terminal:
**hello.py**

```
import firebase_admin
print firebase_admin
```

**Output in terminal:**

```
~/Desktop$ python hello.py
<module 'firebase_admin' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/firebase_admin/__init__.pyc'>
```

Comment: Have you installed the package? `pip install firebase-admin`

Comment: @ThomasMey Yes I installed sudo pip install firebase-admin...it successfully installed..but still this error occurs...

Comment: @ThomasMey  I am using PyCharm in my Linux...Is it any issue for install firebase-admin on local machine?

Comment: I'm using neither Pycharm nor Linux so I can't tell, but I'd recommend to just try it: Open the console, run `python` and enter `import firebase_admin` or just one of the lines above. If it works, it's Pycharm's fault.

Comment: @ThomasMey I have updated my question,have a look...

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37316449/4026792

Your problem is that Pycharm doesn't use the local python iirc

Comment: @ThomasMey In local Pycharm it is added properly,On AppEngine,it shows    same error,No module named firebase_admin.Even on appengine,pip list shows firebase_admin

Comment: Have you vendored the library into your App Engine app? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library

Comment: @hiranya-jayathilaka after vendored the library works fine

Answer (score 16):

Install "firebase-admin" by `pip3 install firebase-admin`

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, confirming your package path of executing program.

[image]

Secondly, **Perferences --> Project Interpreter** ,Make sure the Package install correct path 
[image]

**Anyway**, you should use correct python which is installed the package[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I installed using pip and not pip3.

After correctly installing firebase_admin I also included this on .zshrc:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin:$PATH" 
alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```

Bonus tip:

Check Python version on pyvenv.cfg file, make sure to update Python if necessary and set the latest version to default as described on the first line above. Make sure to replace @3.11 with your latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Hiranya Jayathilaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5190886/hiranya-jayathilaka)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553501/python-firebase-issue-no-module-named-firebase-admin#comment78199114_45553501), third party libraries must be vendored into Google App Engine applications.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to connect `cloud firestore` through `python-admin-sdk` using Visual Studio Code which gave me same error

> Working environment:
>
> 1. Ubuntu 20.04
> 2. Python 3.8.5
> 3. firebase-admin 5.0.0
> 4. Visual Studio Code

**Resolution by re-installing `PyLance` extension in Visual Studio Code.**

Answer (score 0):

After unsuccessfully trying all incarnations of pip to install firebase_admin, what worked for me was **adding firebase_admin in the requirements.txt** file then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

For some reason beyond my understanding, firebase_admin appears to work when installed by referencing the requirements.txt file but not when running pip directly.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue here!
Solved it by updating from python 3.7.9 to 3.9.13
All good now!!!

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I changed my interpreter to an earlier version of Python: I went from 3.11.7.1 to 3.9.6

Answer (score 0):

to solve all the problems regarding this face_recognition module first I have installed cmake in the current working terminal of pycharm using pip install cmake then for the dlib I have used pip install dlib it showed me a error that failed to build wheel I have the installed the wheel from https://github.com/sachadee/Dlib I have done all this in python 3.9 and I have no issues in solving all these errors it is better to use python 3.9.0

Answer (score -7):

update your

> firebase_admin

to the latest version . this will solve the issue .
if nit  rename

> firebase.py

to some other name... Its working

just not use

> firebase.py

as a name for your project and it will work

Comment: That error message is just because missing firebase_admin Python module.
So, how do you "update it to the last version"?

Also, nobody here is using `firebase.py` as Python script name.