# python install PIL on windows

Tags: python, installation, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to install PIL using the Pip method and get the below message. Thanks in advance

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install PIL

Collecting PIL
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL
```

Comment: "Use [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) instead, as PIL is basically dead. Pillow is a maintained fork of PIL." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/installing-pil-with-pip

Comment: And if you can, stick to [Python 3](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/)

Comment: try download http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/