# I Cannot Install Pillow (Using python 2.7.10 on macOS 10.12.6)

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, macos-sierra, python-imaging-library

So, I am really struggling with this one and I have searched everywhere including Stack Overflow for the last 3 hours or so. My problem is I cannot install Pillow using pip (or any other installation package). Here is what I have done so far:

I have managed to install pip itself from the terminal. I used the `sudo easy_install pip`. This was also problematic but I am sure it was installed. When I run `pip --version` in the terminal, I get `pip 10.0.1 from /Users/revogatustesha/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)`, so pip is installed for sure.

Now I cannot install Pillow. I have tried lots of commands but no luck. I have done `easy_install Pillow` in the command line which I think worked, but when I do `from Pillow import image` (and `import image`), it says there is no module named image. I have also done `sudo pip install Pillow` in the terminal and never worked.

I have also tried using homebrew to install it. I installed homebrew, ran the line `brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2` and then `brew install freetype harfbuzz fribidi`. I don't know what to do from here.

Yeah, so this is where I am. Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First question... why use Python 2.7 for a new project when Python 3 has been out for 10 years?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PIL with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/installing-pil-with-pip)