# no module found PIL but it is installed and up2date

Tags: python, macos, scrapy, pip, python-imaging-library

I am trying to download images with scrapy on mac os X and it returns the following error msg:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
$ pip install image
Requirement already satisfied: image in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (1.5.27)
Requirement already satisfied: django in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from image) (1.11.16)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from image) (5.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from django->image) (2013.7)
```

Lets try to install the image package:

```
$ pip install image
Reqfuirement already satisfied: image in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (1.5.27)
Requirement already satisfied: django in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from image) (1.11.16)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from image) (5.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from django->image) (2013.7)
```

Update pip?

```
pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg (18.1)
```

Python ist installe via homebrew

PIP via sudo:  `sudo pip install image`

Also tried:

```
easy_install pip
Password:
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 18.1
Processing pip-18.1-py2.7.egg
pip 18.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

AND:

```
brew unlink python && brew link python
```

More info:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 15, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

MBP:bid user$ type python
python is hashed (/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python)

MBP:bid user$ /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/pip show pip
Name: pip
Version: 18.1
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: pypa-dev@groups.google.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PIL with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/installing-pil-with-pip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Python do you want to use? You seem to claim you installed Python via **homebrew** but you are using Python 2.7 as supplied by Apple in `/usr/bin/python` and that is why pip is installing in `/Library/Python/2.7`.

If you want to use **homebrew** Python and `pip` you need to be running `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python`. You can see all this information if you run:

```
brew info python
```

In general, anything that looks in or is installed in `/anywhere/LOCAL/anywhere` will be **homebrew**. Anything that uses `/usr/bin` or `/Library/anywhere` will be Apple-supplied.

---

If you want to know which actual command you are running, use `type` like this:

```
type python
python is hashed (/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python)
```

So that tells me that, on my machine, `python` is the one in `/usr/local/...` which must be from **homebrew** because it contains `/.../LOCAL/...`

Your `python` is currently `/usr/bin/python`. If you want to use the **homebrew** one, you need to change your PATH in you login profile and put `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin` **before** `/usr/bin`. E.g.:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH
```

Then start a new Terminal so that you are running with the new profile.

---

Note the difference:

```
# Run the old Apple-supplied Python
/usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.10

# Run the shiny new homebrew Python
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python -V
Python 3.7.1

# Run the homebrew pip - that installs into /something/LOCAL/something - sure sign it is not Apple's
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/pip show pip
Name: pip
Version: 18.1
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: pypa-dev@groups.google.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Comment: I did the export command and now I get the 3.7.1 version in the same terminal. However if I open a new terminal, I am getting the old version. Within the terminal running 3.7.1 the same problem occures, I posted the output as addtional info to the question. Looks OK to me, but still the same errror.

Comment: You need to edit your login profile, and do the `export` in there too - it is probably `$HOME/.profile` then it will set the PATH every time you log in. When you get `python -V` and `pip -V` telling you the **homebrew** version, you will need to run `pip install pillow` because, at the moment, you have installed Pillow for Apple Python v2.7