# Converting Python file to .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a Python file that I want to convert to .exe using pyinstaller.
I get this error,
[image]

I searched how to solve this and the solution was to install Pillow package. After I installed it, I face the same error again and I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Did you rebuild the EXE after installing Pillow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/installing-pil-with-pip?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: yes I did and the same problem occurred again @AKX

Comment: I'll give it a shot @Sheri

Comment: @AdelMoustafa Could you try and run pyinstaller in Anaconda? If it executes there then it is likely an environment issue. Let me know

Comment: @newcoder it executes, but  i am having the same kind of problem

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of PIL have an exposed Image class. Try this:

```
import Image
```

You can get more info on this from the [official tutorial](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm).