# how to install PIL with pip?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

when I run the following

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image




root.mainloop()
```

I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_viewer.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

but I already install Pillow and everything is fine.

Comment: If "__everything is fine__", what is your question now

Comment: Maybe you have different versions of Python on your computer and installed Pillow for the wrong one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install PIL with pip on Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/how-to-install-pil-with-pip-on-mac-os)

Comment: If you're using PyCharm then you have to install modules through the PyCharm application.  Also, it could be a version thing. 
 Try `pip3 install Pillow` and check out https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#packages-tool-window

Answer (score 29):

Use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/) which is the "new" or the replacement of [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil), but has the same-named modules to preserve compatibility:

```
pip install pillow
```

Also, as suggested in the comments, maybe you are just using the wrong python binary, try to check if you're in/out of a virtual environment or check differences between `python` vs `python3` vs `python2` on your system:

```
python -m pip list
python2 -m pip list
python3 -m pip list
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not running the same python interpreter. In addition, the problem could arise from this fact that python cannot find the path to the OpenCV.

You first need to find the path to the OpenCV installed on your OS.

First, open a python script and run this:

```
import cv2
PATH = cv2.__file__
print(PATH)
```

This will print the PATH to the OpenCV installed on your OS.

Then, add the following two lines to the top of your main script (before calling tkinter and PIL):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('PATH')
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image




root.mainloop()
```

**Alternative Solution:**

The problem could be that you are not running the same python interpreter.

You first need to find the path to the python executable that is interpreting your python scripts.

Open a python script and run this:

```
import sys
PATH = sys.executable
print(PATH)
```

This will print the path to the python executable that is interpreting your python scripts.

Now, you can install pillow in the found path as follows:

```
PATH -m pip install pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you already installed pillow use this command `pip install pillow --upgrade`, then you can use the command `pip freeze` to list all modules that have been installed.