# How to manage Pillow package in lambda function?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-imaging-library

I get this like error in my lambda function; I have uploaded the entire package but I got same error:

[image]

> Exception: You don't have PIL installed. Please install PIL or Pillow>=8.1.1

How can I install PIL on lambda?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install PIL with pip on Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/how-to-install-pil-with-pip-on-mac-os)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pre-packaged Lambda layer, such as the ones found in [this repository](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers). The specific link will depend on your region and your Lambda's Python version.

Alternatively, you can package the layer yourself. The [official guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/packaging-layers.html) also uses Pillow as an example.