# Converting base64 images to base64 JPG

Tags: python, image, base64

I have a feature with my application where a user can upload a photo. I would like to convert the photo into a JPG file and then upload it to my servers.

The photo is received in base64. I've seen [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6966225/2961662) which suggest using PIL however, it saves the image to a local directory. Instead I would like to convert the received image into a base64 JPG image.

How would I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand, you have base64 of a jpg file and you want to get the jpg file? Just decode it  data.decode('base64')

Comment: Sorry, I ment that I have a base64 of any image file, for example a .png and I would like to convert it into base64 .jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import base64
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
output = BytesIO()
im.save(output, 'JPEG')
jpg_img = output.read()
```

it will save the data to a stream ( the same way tou enter it) and then you can read from that stream

Comment: Thanks. This will not save the image to a file though right?

Comment: Right, it will only keep it in memory